# Small program to calculate lowest, highest, and average of numbers in array (recalling C++)

Tags: c++

It's been a while since I worked with C++ and decided to try solving a problem just to help me recall old material.

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a small program (with Visual Studio) that:
- Asks the user to enter 10 scores
- Calculate the lowest, highest, and average scores.
- Displays all the 10 scores, along with the lowest, highest, and average.

This is the code I've written:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    int sum = 0;
    int avg = 0;
    int low = 0;
    int high = 0;
    int array[10];

    cout << "Please enter 10 scores" << endl;
    cout << " - - - - - - - - - - - " << endl; 

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a score: ";
        cin >> i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];

        if (array[i] < array[i]+1)
        {
            low = array[i];
        }
        else if (array[i]+1 < array[i])
        {
            high = array[i];
        }
        else
            low = array[i];
    }
    avg = sum/10;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "The lowest score is: " << low << endl;
    cout << "...and the highest score is: " << high << endl;
    cout << "The average score is: " << avg << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I just wanted to know if I was on track. Once again, I'm trying to create a small program that:
- Asks the user to enter 10 scores
- Calculate the lowest, highest, and average scores.
- Displays all the 10 scores, along with the lowest, highest, and average.

It's been a while since I've worked with C++ and just wanted to know if I was on track to solving this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Chris Drew: Oh, pardon me. I thought I was done typing. One moment...

Comment: @Chris Drew: Fixed. My apologies.

Comment: Your question could still use some clarity. Your application compiles, but I'm guessing it doesn't work. You should rephrase your question to include that it doesn't do what you want it to do (e.g. sometimes it doesn't allow all 10 numbers to be inserted, sometimes it allows more, the lowest number isn't properly calculated etc) and ensure you include the desired behaviour (which I believe you have)

Comment: @G_Man `It's been a while since I worked with C++`  That implies that you have been working with some other language.   Loops to calculate the lowest, highest, and average basically all look the same with most any language that have similarities to C++.

Comment: @Tas Well, it only allows me to enter one number, which is something I thought I could solve that's why I didn't include it in the question. But I've gotten some good answers so far, some pointing out other errors I didn't notice. My apologies for not being clear with my question. I guess basically what I was asking was if my code made sense (so far) when held side-by-side with what I was trying to get it to do, a progress report of sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some mistakes of your code:

1. If you want to take take 10 items then you have to iterate loop from 0 to 9 not 10 so `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`
2. You have to take `array[i]`, not only `i`
3. If you want to compare you have to write `if (array[i] < array[i+1])`
4. Comparing isn't correct. You are comparing between two items and storing high/low among them.

Total code after editing:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    int sum = 0;
    int avg = 0;
    int low = 999999;
    int high = 0;
    int array[11];

    cout << "Please enter 10 scores" << endl;
    cout << " - - - - - - - - - - - " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a score: ";
        cin >> array[i];
        //sum+=array[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];

        if (array[i] < low)
        {
            low = array[i];
        }

        if (array[i] > high)
        {
            high = array[i];
        }
    }
    avg = sum/10;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "The lowest score is: " << low << endl;
    cout << "...and the highest score is: " << high << endl;
    cout << "The average score is: " << avg << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified way

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter score " << i+1 << " : ";
    cin >> a[i];
}

high = low = a[0];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << a[i] << endl;

    sum += array[i];

    if (array[i] < low)
       low = array[i];

    else if (array[i] > high)
        high = array[i];
 }
```

Comment: Because at the end he wants to display the entered score one by one else  single loop will do